# Ionic 4 custom styling of popover, modal components or pages

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

My app in Ionic 4 but I can’t understand how to customize components.
And i want to display alignment position top right corner.

I have tried in global.css file as well as component.css file , but didn't any luck.

```
async getNotifications() {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: NotificationComponent,
      // event: ev,
      cssClass: 'notificationCSS',
      translucent: true
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }
```

In notificationCSS :

```
 .notificationCSS{
      top: 0px !important;
      right: 0px !important;
  }
```

[Ref. Url](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)

Comment: put cssClass in global.scss

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in ionic for dynamically (maybe not exactly correct in angnular world) rendered html elements. My component css file didn't pick up the classes that I was targetting. However global.css did. I would try put your css in global again.

Comment: Thanks @f1vlad ,  it works by inheriting popover-content class `.notificationCSS .popover-content`